# jQuery-File-Upload -- identify file uniquely across its lifecycle

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the **basic setup** of [jQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) in a Rails app, i.e. I'm not using the stock UI or server-side scripts. The on-page UX that I want is very different from the one bundled in the plugin.

I'm using the `add`, `done`, and `progress` callbacks to implement the UX I want. However, I can't figure out how to uniquely identify a particular file across it's entire "upload lifecycle". For each file that is being uploaded I want to create a `div` and display the progress bar and file thumbnail inside it.

Right now I'm using the file-name of the uploaded file to identify it across the life cycle and tie it to a particular `div` However, that will break as soon as a user uploads two (or more) files with the same name.

How do I solve this?

(Have I described the problem properly? Do let me know if it's too vague or ambiguous).

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of the callback (data) is related to the upload, so for example you can save 'reference' to the html progress related to the upload.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    add: function (e, data) {
                data.whatever = $('<div></div>');
            }
});
```